# How do I disable gestures in Mapbox v10.0?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

The guide mentions disabling User Interactions for Kotlin [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/user-interaction/#enable-and-disable-default-gestures).

```
mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView)
mapboxMap = mapView.getMapboxMap()
mapboxMap.gestures();  //Method not found??
```

I don't know how to code in Kotlin. I can't work it around to work with Java. In Java, it says it cannot resolve symbol 'gestures'.
Same problem with other features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the GesturesPlugin,  try this:

```
final  GesturesPlugin gesturesPlugin = GesturesUtils.getGestures((mapView));
        gesturesPlugin.setPitchEnabled(false);
        gesturesPlugin.setScrollEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: Can you also tell how to add markers?

Answer (score 1):

I used the following methods to disable everything related to the map movement on mapbox 10

```
binding.mapView.gestures.pitchEnabled = false
binding.mapView.gestures.scrollEnabled = false
binding.mapView.gestures.pinchToZoomEnabled = false
binding.mapView.gestures.rotateEnabled = false
```